# Apex Iterating through Contact's Opportunities Strange Error

Tags: apex, opportunity, contact, developer-console

Im getting the following error:

> The configuration of your org has changed, please reload the page.  Missing dependent object: Field: Opportunity.ContactId

This happens in the for loop declaration below:

```
private static void checkContactOpps(Contact contact)
{
    for (Opportunity opp : contact.Opportunities)
    {

    }
}
```

And this is how I query for the Contacts and the related Opps

```
//Retrieve the Accounts associated with the Contacts
    List<Contact> contactAcctIds = new List<Contact>(
        [SELECT AccountId,
                (SELECT Id,
                        Name,
                        RecordTypeId,
                        Product_Interest__c,
                        Type,
                        CloseDate,
                        StageName,
                        Season__c,
                        Ticket_Type__c,
                        LeadSource,
                        AccountId
                 FROM Opportunities)
         FROM Contact
         WHERE Id IN :contactIds
        ]
    );
```

I tried searching online, but I couldn't find any relevant solution to the problem. I'm a System Admin too, so I don't think its a permissions issue.

Comment: FYI [How to get Opportunities from Contacts](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69070/how-to-get-opportunities-from-contacts) that includes an unaccepted answer that says "This field is a bug and should not be used. It is technical debt that SFDC has not cleaned up yet." and has various other comments.

Answer (score 2):

@keithc should write the accepted answer, but to further elaborate when faced with issues like this:

If you look in Workbench, there is no child relationship from Contact to Opportunities: 
[image]

nor a lookup relationship from Opportunity to Contact:

[image]

So, if the object, field, or relationship is not visible to the metadata browser, it won't be available to your application.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! That makes perfect sense since the Contact Role is the junction object between the two.